# Composer installed net-snmp?

Tags: php, composer-php

I figured there are probably enough composer (getcomposer.org) users on here that might be able to answer this.

I've got composer installed globally (in /usr/local/bin)..

I was getting a message that composer was over 30 days old and needed to updated.  So I 'sudo composer self-update'.

I noticed it did the following:

Created directory: /var/db/net-snmp
Created directory: /var/db/net-snmp/mib_indexes
Updating to version .
    Downloading: 100%

it's a folder locked down to root, and I looked into it and see only a single file named 0 in mib_indexes .. It looks to contain a list of text files.

Anyone know what happened?  Why did it create a net-snmp db folder?  Is this normal behavior?

Comment: I got the same problem today when I did sudo composer create-project... Just wondering how did you finally deal with it? Is it safe to let the folder remains there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely not normal behavior. All `self-update` does is download a new phar from getcomposer.org and then overwrites itself with it. It should not, and usually(?) does not touch anything else on your file-system.

Comment: It's weird.. I rm-rd'd the directories, ran sudo composer self-update, and it recreated them..

No log handling enabled - using stderr logging
Created directory: /var/db/net-snmp
Created directory: /var/db/net-snmp/mib_indexes
You are using the latest composer version.

Comment: I think this is above my pay grade, but my guess is this is harmless. Looking around the net, this seems to happen alot when running a php script as root, and I found a setting for it in /usr/bin/net-snmp-config.. Going to get a fresh instance of OSX and see if I can replicate it that way just to rule out anything fishy.. Would be easier if net-snmp wasn't such a mystery to me. :)

Comment: Yeah I have no idea what net-snmp is, but I am fairly sure it is not related to Composer :) In any case good luck finding out what's going on. I'd be curious to know.